# Cannot access RavenDB Management Studio with Embedded Db

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb-http

I run and initialize an instance using the following code:

```
        EmbeddableDocumentStore db = new EmbeddableDocumentStore();
        db.DataDirectory = @"C:\RavenDb\";
        db.Configuration.HostName = "localhost";
        db.Configuration.Port = 8080;
        db.UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true;
        db.Initialize();
```

After initializing and keeping the app in debug mode I try to access the management studio on my browser through "localhost:8080" but the request times out/ nothing happens. I tried different ports, I start VS2012 in Admin mode. I downloaded the latest versions through Nuget. What am I doing wrong/ not seeing here?

Thanks

Edit: After couple suggestions I tried the following code, still to no avail:

```
        NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
        EmbeddableDocumentStore db = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
        {
            RunInMemory = true,
            DataDirectory = @"C:\RavenDb\",
            UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
        };

        db.Initialize();
```

In addition I received the following warning messages in the output window upon running the console application:

Resulting in: Cannot set import 'Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.OAuthClientCredentialsTokenResponder.AuthenticateClient (ContractName="Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.IAuthenticateClient")' on part 'Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.OAuthClientCredentialsTokenResponder'.
Element: Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.OAuthClientCredentialsTokenResponder.AuthenticateClient (ContractName="Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.IAuthenticateClient") -->  Raven.Database.Server.Security.OAuth.OAuthClientCredentialsTokenResponder -->  AssemblyCatalog (Assembly="Raven.Database, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37f41c7f99471593")

Comment: Remove the hostname setting, and it should work

Comment: @AyendeRahien, I removed it, no change, it does not work. I also tried Yogi's code snippet. No luck either.

Comment: By the way, when I run Raven.Server.exe I have no problem getting into management studio. Its causing problems when I run the embedded document store as indicated in the snipped above

Comment: I added some information from the output window upon running the client in a console application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one solution for the nuget pakage

```
<package id="RavenDB.Embedded" version="2.0.2230" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Make sure the port is not in use

```
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
{
    RunInMemory = true,
    DataDirectory = @"C:\RavenDb\",
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
};

documentStore.Initialize();
```

Comment: no change, "localhost:8080" within my browser gets me nowhere. The port is not blocked.  ;-(

Comment: I double checked, I run on version 2.0.2230 for all 3 installed RavenDB components

Comment: I added some warning messages I captured in the output window.

Comment: Looks like a similar issue was raised: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/zJbA3fG3cAo

Comment: well currently it looks like this renders RavenDB pretty much useless if the requirement is to run embedded. The Management Studio is currently the only way to manage the database.

Comment: RavenDB uses REST and JSON so you could use Fiddler or even cURL to access the DB. LinqPad has a driver too.

Comment: how would that work if RavenDB does not even expose the http server? Sorry I guess I sound a bit pessimistic here, its just I was quite impressed with everything I have seen about RavenDB until I hit a brick wall. The disappointing issue is that this bug seems to have been around for more than a year and it has apparently still not been fixed. (I googled and found posts referring to similar error messages)

Comment: Have a look at the HTTP API: http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api/http-api-single and as a first step try this url in a browser (I use FireFox): http://localhost:8080/docs/

Comment: I think I found the problem. I have no idea why but after I initialize I set a break point in order to check whether the server was setup. I now just have the console wait through `Console.Readline()` and the server responds without problems. I have no idea why but it apparently works.

Comment: If your program is stopped on a breakpoint, then all threads are suspended, including those used by RavenDB Embedded. As such it can't respond to any requests.